# What is the code to add physics to the rigidbody in unity 5.0.0p2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript, rigid-bodies

The following code seems to be wrong in Unity 5.0.0p2:

```
rigidbody2D.velocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 10;
```

So I tried the following code:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 10;
```

But still it is not working. Several error messages appear as follows.

- `BCE0043: Unexpected token: ).`
- `BCE0044: expecting ), found '.'.`
- `UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.`

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first line will no longer work because rigidbody2D is no longer a property of a MonoBehaviour. This has been removed, so you will have to use a `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` instead.

That doesn't fully fix your problem however. You cannot update a `velocity` like you do, by only setting the `x` value. You will have to assign the full vector. So copy your current `velocity` to a Vector3 of its own, update `x` and replace the whole `velocity` vector.

Comment: Thank you! I added Vector3 and it worked. Here is my code, `var moveHorizontal : float= Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    var movement : Vector3= new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0, 0);
    var rb: Rigidbody2D;
    rb = GetComponent.<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = movement * 4; `

Answer (score 1):

The error messages probably don't relate to the line you posted as that seems OK, though we'd need the whole script to say.

However, as for the velocity of rigidbody, assign it like this:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(
    Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 10,
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y
);
```

This sets only the `x` axis of the velocity and keeps the `y` axis.

Comment: I tried this but it did't work. Several error messages appeared as "BCE0043: Unexpected token: ).", "BCE0044: expecting ), found '.'.", "UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end.", "BCE0043: Unexpected token: )." etc.